# About the JDBC RowSet

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

i know about what a RowSet is and all; what i would like to know is if it works properly and is accepted already, or if it still has it's bugs and isn't as widely accepted as the classic ResultSet. it looks good to me so far, but i want to hear more experienced views on the subject.

Comment: A RowSet is a disconnected serializable version of a JDBC ResultSet.

Comment: @adatapost, RowSets are connected, CachedRowSets, WebRowSets etc are disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two factors in deciding if you RowSet is right for you:

1) Can you have the whole result in memory? Sometimes you need to parse the result set one row at a time and can't just get the whole thing in memory at once.

2) Have you tested your JDBC driver for the behavior with RowSet?

I think #2 is where you start with your question. The truth is that it is basically implementation dependent if a given RowSet is robust and production ready. In theory, you can use a RowSet implementation from a different vendor than the JDBC driver as well, and that should work as well.

Comment: +1 for testing the JDBC driver support. 5 years ago when I was learning Java (coming from .net), I was puzzled about the number of bugs in RowSet. Turned out to be the JDBC driver's fault.

Comment: well i'm using MySQL so i hope i'm right in assuming that the driver should work properly as both products are from sun...

Answer (score 3):

**RowSet**

1. RowSet makes life a lot easier for
   all JDBC programmers. No more
   Connection objects, statement
   objects, just a single RowSet will
   do everything for you.
2. Rowsets make it easy to send tabular
   data over a network. They can also
   be used to provide scrollable result
   sets or updatable result sets when
   the underlying JDBC driver does not
   support them.
3. RowSet object follows the JavaBeans
   model for properties and event
   notification, it is a JavaBeans
   component that can be combined with
   other components in an application.
4. Rowsets may have many different
   implementations to fill different
   needs. These implementations fall
   into two broad categories, rowsets
   that are connected and those that
   are disconnected.

[RowSet Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/chapter5.html)

Comment: haha, so sorry, i don't mean to be rude and i appreciate your answer, but i think you didn't read my question. i was asking whether it was widely accepted, or it still had criticisms and people still preferred the ResultSet. sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Yes, RowSet is far better than ResultSet. Ofcourse it is correct but there are some situations where we need to use ResultSet only.

Comment: can you elaborate further when it's more desirable to use a ResultSet? i can't see what ResultSet can do that RowSet can't